# UpdateCursor: Invalid input value for setting

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, valueerror

I have a field called "CODE_12" in which the values are strings (3 characters). I have another empty field called "AE" and that I want to fill depending on the value on the "CODE_12" field. For example, when the CODE_12 field is equal to 112 I want the AE field to have a value of 396. I have tried using the UpdateCursor but I'm getting the error "Invalid input value for setting". Any idea of what I´m doing wrong? I attache my code

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(RainLandUnion) # This is my feature layer
for row in rows:
         if row.getValue("CODE_12") == "112":
            row.setValue("AE", 396.71)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "221":
                 row.setValue("AE",435.920)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "321":
             row.setValue=("AE", 438.2)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "242":
             row.setValue= ("AE",425.45)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "243":
             row.setValue= ("AE",425.45)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "324":
             row.setValue=("AE",441.64)
         elif row.getValue("CODE_12") == "313":
             row.setValue= ("AE",441.64)
         rows.updateRow(row)
```

The full error message is :

> Message   File Name   Line    Position     Traceback
>         C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Nuenna\nuenna shapes\model_sample\ae_calc.py 51
>       **setattr**   C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py   35
>   exceptions.ValueError: Row: Invalid input value for setting

Comment: You should really look into using the Data Access (da) updatecursor - they're much faster.  Details on that here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/updatecursor.htm  

I'm not 100 percent certain on this - but  you may want to cast your numbers to string when you write them to the feature as in: `row.setValue("AE",str(441.64))`

Comment: @Kevin that link is for ArcGIS Pro.  For ArcGIS 10.2 the link would be http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000

Comment: Your indentation is slightly astray but I think the error may be saying that you are trying to push floating point values into a field that is defined as something else (e.g. long, short, text)

Comment: @Kevin I have also tried with the DA updatecursor and it wasn't working, but anyway I would need to keep the AE field as double since I'll use it to calculate another field afterwards.

Comment: @PolyGeo the field is defined as Double, and i fixed the indentation

Comment: In that case can you change the code that you appear to have copy/pasted from your full script into a code snippet that starts with `import arcpy` and will work up until the point that you are stuck, and then show us the error that results from running precisely the code snippet that you present.

Comment: @lia - My mistake about the casting.  Sorry about that, it's almost quitting time, my reading comprehension isn't at it's peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some `=` in the wrong place in some of your `setValue` lines - `row.setValue("AE",435.920)` in some lines, and `row.setValue=("AE", 438.2)` in others.

Also, try using a dictionary of update values rather than `if/elif`

Using `arcpy.UpdateCursor()`:

```
updateValDict = {"112": 396.71, "221": 435.920, "321": 438.2, "242": 425.45, "243": 425.45, "324": 441.64, "313": 441.64}
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(RainLandUnion) # This is my feature layer
for row in rows:
    c12 = row.getValue("CODE_12")
    if row.getValue("CODE_12") in updateValDict:
        row.setValue("AE", updateValDict[c12])
    rows.updateRow(row)
```

Using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`:

```
updateValDict = {"112": 396.71, "221": 435.920, "321": 438.2, "242": 425.45, "243": 425.45, "324": 441.64, "313": 441.64}
fields = ["CODE_12", "AE"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(RainLandUnion, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in updateValDict:
            row[1] = updateValDict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I'd not spotted those `=` signs.